# Disassembling a String Into an Array at every '<br>'-Tag

Tags: java, regex, oop, math

I have a string which is:

```
<p>1+: €0,09756<br>3.001+: €0,09338<br>
30.001+: €0,09338<br>150.001+: €0,09338<br>
750.001+: €0,09338<br>
</p>
```

Now what I would like to do is I would like to call `article.addPrice(new Integer(quantity), new Float(price));` for each of these lines which are separated by the `<br>`. Meaning the result is:

```
article.addPrice(new Integer(1), new Float(0.09756));
article.addPrice(new Integer(3001), new Float(0.09338));
article.addPrice(new Integer(30001), new Float(0.09338));
article.addPrice(new Integer(150001), new Float(0.09338));
article.addPrice(new Integer(750001), new Float(0.09338));
```

The integer is stripped of all special characters, the float too. The currency symbol will be ignored. If the Price of the next line is the same as the one before the `article.addPrice` will not be performed.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the followig regular expression?

```
(\d+(,\d+)?)\+: €(\d+(,\d+)?(\.\d+)?)
```

EDIT (courtesy of abhusava):

```
String str = "<p>1+: €0.09756<br>3,001+: €0.09338<br>\n" + 
   "30,001+: €0.09338<br>150,001+: €0.09338<br>750,001+: €0.09338<br></p>";

Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(,\\d+)?)\\+: €(\\d+(,\\d+)?(\\.\\d+)?)");
Matcher m = pt.matcher(str);    
Float lastPrice = null;

while(m.find()) {
  Integer quantity = new Integer(m.group(1).replace(",",""));
  Float price = new Float(m.group(3).replace(",","").replace(".",","));

  // Only add price if different from last
  if (! price.equals(lastPrice))
    article.addPrice(quantity, price);
  lastPrice = price;
}
```

Comment: how would I run the method for each line and how would I access the two variables?

Comment: This is good, except it will turn <p>1+: €0.64974<br>51+: €0.53337<br>401+: €0.51051<br>2,001+: €0.51051<br>10,001+: €0.51051<br></p> into

1 : 64974.0 EUR // 51 : 53337.0 EUR // 401 : 51051.0 EUR // 1 : 51051.0 EUR // 1 : 51051.0 EUR

Comment: and it will add elements even though the previous element has the same price

Comment: @JackMurphy As to the slightly expensive prices, this depends on your input (is dots or commas used as thousand separator or decimal point?). Modify the replace("SEPARATOR","NEWSEPARATOR") statements to match.

Comment: @JackMurphy Sorry, missed the point about comparing with last element, I've edited the answer. Note that the current answer only compares with last element, so if the prices don't come in order you might add duplicates.

Comment: it worked well with the prices, I just replaced the "." by "". But with the 2,001 for example the line gives me back 1, even though I substitute the "," by "".

Comment: @JackMurphy I've modified the answer (switching dots and commas). The current assumption is to use commas as thousand separator and dots as decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, split the string with `s.split("<br>")`. That gives you an array of strings as requested. You also need to eliminate the starting `<p>`. Then you can split each entry in the array with `split("\\+: €")`. That leaves you with a two-element array of strings parseable into numbers, except for the comma, you need to replace it with a dot: `s.replace(',', '.')`. Finally, use `Integer.parseInt` and `Float.parseFloat`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
String str = "<p>1+: €0,09756<br>3.001+: €0,09338<br>\n" + 
   "30.001+: €0,09338<br>150.001+: €0,09338<br>750.001+: €0,09338<br></p>";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("([^\\+]+)\\D+([\\d,]+)");
Matcher m = pt.matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1).replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
    float price = Float.parseFloat(m.group(2).replace(',', '.'));
    System.out.printf("article.addPrice(new Integer(%d), new Float(%f));%n",
                       quantity, price);
}
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
article.addPrice(new Integer(1), new Float(0.09756));
article.addPrice(new Integer(3001), new Float(0.09338));
article.addPrice(new Integer(30001), new Float(0.09338));
article.addPrice(new Integer(150001), new Float(0.09338));
article.addPrice(new Integer(750001), new Float(0.09338));
```